# How to get to new XML page by clicking a button?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have two XML pages called `activity_main` and `layout2`. The first one is a simple blank screen with a button in the middle of it. The second XML page is just a blank screen. I want to be able to go to the second XML page by clicking the button on the first XML page.

This is the code I used for the first java activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        final Context context = this;
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }
```

The `startActivity(intent)` was used to start a new intent, in this case, the following java activity:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity{
    Button button;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
    }

}
```

When I run this in the emulator and press the button, the program crashes and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: did you define the second Activity in your manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you include in your manifest:

```
   <activity android:name="com.package_name.MainActivity2"/>
```

replacing com.package_name with whatever your package name is.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
```

and define your second activity in manifest